# PLSQL: how to send clob to remote database

Tags: oracle, batch-file, plsql, clob, remote-server

The situation is : I want to export table to XML file locally on DB1, and then import this xml on remote database DB2. I already have the procedure to do export and import, but how to send the data to the remote server?

I want to write a batch file to do export locally first , it can generate an xml file or return a clob string. then import the data into remote database server.

How could I do that ?

Comment: both databases are Oracle? if so why aren't you just using the supplied exp/imp (or datapump) to do this?

Comment: @DazzaL Yes, Both are Oracle. But the data in xml file are not direct from tables, it has been filtered and nested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this discussion on AskTom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:52297289480186), it seems you can't fetch a CLOB over a Database Link.

However, there are many LOB operations that work over a DBLink. You can *SELECT* a LOB over a database link for instance.

In your case, you could create a Global Temporary Table in DB1 that would contain your CLOB and import this clob directly in DB2.

In DB1 you would have:

- A temporary table `GTT (temp_data XMLFile) -- or CLOB`
- A procedure that `proc` extracts/filters your XMLFile and inserts into the temporary table `GTT`

In DB2:

- A database Link `DBL1` to DB1
- You would call `proc@DBL1`,
- then `INSERT INTO dest_table (dest_col) (SELECT temp_data FROM gtt@DBL1)`